# Return result in json format - Apache Spark Sql

Tags: java, json, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am new to Apache spark Sql and now I am using spark java api to query data from hive. Here is the code I have used which is from Spark documentation

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark").setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
HiveContext sqlContext = new .HiveContext(ctx.sc());
Row[] result = = sqlContext.sql("Select * from TableName").collect();
```

Now I am using for loop to loop through the result and concatenating as json string and it is very slow and is there any other way to achieve this?
Can any one tell me how to do this.